# Understanding python's argparse module

Tags: python, command-line, arguments, argparse

I am trying to work with argparse in python and I do not know how to call the program at command line to see if it works.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("DocID", type= int, help= "Insert DocID Here")
parser.add_argument("echo", help = "Enter in the FileName to be read")
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

This is my incredibly basic program that I am trying to use just to learn more about how argparse works. I just need to learn how and where to call the program to be able to use the arguments I give it.

Edit: To make my question more clear sorry. I have this code, but I do not know how to call the program as a whole so that I can run it. Like how would I run this in command line? Because when run just in IDLE it produces and error because of a lack of commands

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you read [that](http://docs.python.org/howto/argparse.html)?

Comment: Argument names are usually preceded by a '--' or a '-'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

an ArgumentParser's `parse_args` method can take a list as input.  That list is used for parsing the commandline arguments.  So, a common idiom is:

```
args = parser.parse_args('-a -b -c --value=True'.split())
```

since `str.split` returns a list. (`'a b c'.split() == ['a', 'b', 'c']`)

---

Usually when you add arguments, you do so like this:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', '--a-long-name', type=int, ...)
```

Arguments without a `-` or `--` in front are positional arguments, so both of your arguments are positional.  You can see a little of what is happening if you do:

```
args = parser.parse_args(['1','foo'])
print args.DocID # 1
print args.echo  # foo
```

which is the same as calling your script as `python youscript.py 1 foo` (without the list inside `parse_args`).

Comment: How can I make the script 'python youscript.py arg1 arg 2' work though. This is my real issue, that I get the python is not recognized as a command error

Comment: Then it seems that you have python installed in a non-standard place (outside of `path`).  What OS are you using?  If on *NIX, try the path to python pointed to by `idle`.  In other words, `head $(which idle)` will have a path to python coded into the first line.  try that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the command line syntax of the script... just call it with --help, argparse automatically provides it for you.

```
⚫  gbin@sal tmp % python test.py --help
usage: test.py [-h] DocID echo

positional arguments:
  DocID       Insert DocID Here
  echo        Enter in the FileName to be read

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```